# Set implementation in UPPAAL

Tags: modeling, verification, promela, uppaal

I have a model which in which a process needs to choose an element `s` randomly from the the set `S`. The choosing part is a single operation. The only similar data structure I know in UPPAAL is arrays.

Does there exist a **set** data structure in UPPAAL?  If not, then how can I create one?

Answer (score 0):

Unless a set data structure has been added recently recently (as in the last 10 years or so) there is no such thing in the language.

I would model the choice as a process with one location and |S| edges, each one setting a shared variable (the choice) to a different value from S. To trigger the choice I would use synchronization on an urgent channel.

Answer (score 0):

If your set S is finite and countable, then try using bounded integer type.
For example:

```
const int N = 10; // size of the whole domain
typedef int[1,N] range_t; // range of possible elements: indexed 1..N
typedef int[0,N-1] crange_t; // C-programmers may prefer indexed 0..N-1
bool S[range_t]; // boolean array encoding of membership
```

then you can make an edge choosing any element from S like this:

```
select: e:range_t
guard: S[e]
sync:  hey[e]!
update: chosen_one=e
```

Comment: if the members are symmetric, then a symmetry reduction is applicable (yields exponential speedup) by declaring a symmetric range type: `typedef scalar[N] symrange_t`.